Updating contacts doesn't work in Flutter with package [contacts_service]
I am using contact_service plugin to update users contact in my Flutter app.
When I update an old contact, no error occurs, but the phone number is removed from the contact list.
here is my modification code.
the code just needs to modify the phone numbers, the new number is in the modifiedNumber variable
  void _updateSelectedContacts() {
    setState(() {
      for (var contact in contacts) {
        final id = contact.identifier ?? contact.displayName ?? '';
        if (selectedContacts[id] == true) {
          final updatedPhones = contact.phones?.map((phone) {
            final modifiedNumber = modifyBeninNumber(phone.value ?? "");
            return Item(label: phone.label, value: modifiedNumber);
          }).toList();

          if (updatedPhones != null) {
            contact.phones = updatedPhones;
            print(contact.displayName);
            // update contact
            ContactsService.updateContact(contact);
          }
        }
      }

      // remove selected contact
      selectedContacts.updateAll((key, value) => false);
      _selectAll = false;
    });

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('Contacts updated successfully!')),
    );
  }


Try add asynchronies method and use await for update like this:
  await ContactsService.updateContact(contact); // UPDATE CONTACT

